# select Top 3 unexpexted result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is table structure !

> name varchar(10),
>
> score float

With values:

```
('Alex',7),('john',5.6),('Tom',8.9),('Anonio',6),('sharti',7),('mamuzi',9)
```

I need o/p

```
name    score
mamuzi  9
Tom 8.9
Alex    7
sharti  7
```

When i try using `TOP` as : `select top 3  * from table order by score desc` I can't get the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `with Ties` in sql server since `Alex and sharti` have same score

```
select top 3 with ties * from #t order by score desc
```

## [See here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15258)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you include an `ORDER BY` statement, the ordering will be random when you use TOP.

Do this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES * FROM YourTable ORDER BY score DESC
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1af5f/1).

From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

> When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result
>   set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it
>   returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order.

**Edit: just noticed the change in your sample data. To make it work now you need to add the `WITH TIES` clause to TOP, as pointed out in the other answers. I've updated my answer accordingly.**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot *ordering by* `score` field. Modify your query as:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC
```

---

Answer for the last edit to your question: Using `TOP` and `ORDER BY DESC` worked for me but i tested with the new values you added to your question. My test was as follows:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  name varchar(10),
  score float
) 

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('Alex', 7)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('john',5.6)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('Tom',8.9)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('Anonio',6)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('sharti',7)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('mamuzi',9)

SELECT TOP 3 * FROM @table ORDER BY score DESC
```

It works since the result is as expected.

To include `sharti` and his score in the results since he has the same score as `Alex`, you will need to use `WITH TIES` as [Vijaykumar Hadalgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010659/select-top-3-unexpexted-result/22010747#22010747) suggested ([More](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/480781/SQL-Server-TOP-WITH-TIES-A-Beauty-of-TSQL) for WITH TIES).

Modify your query as: `SELECT TOP(3) WITH TIES * FROM @table ORDER BY score DESC`

```
name    score
--------------
mamuzi  9
Tom     8,9
Alex    7
sharti  7
```

Comment: @user2841280 i did. But the solution stands the same.

Comment: what abt record `shrati 7` it shares same score rite ? 7 so in this case ther's a tie btw 2 so you need to use `with ties` instead !

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi you are correct, the OP asks for the *extended* result. Thanks for pointing