# LINQ to Entities equivalent of sql "TOP(n) WITH TIES"

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have been searcing for `LINQ` equivalent of `WITH TIES` in *sql server* lately, I came across a couple things, which couldn't proove to be useful.

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342848/does-linq-to-sql-have-a-with-ties-option) was asked before and has an accepted answer, but it doesn't work the way with ties *does*. The solution using `GroupBy()` doesn't result as expected for `TOP(3) WITH TIES` considering a data set consisting of `{3 2 2 1 1 0}` the result set will be `{3 2 2 1 1}` where it should be `{3 2 2}`

Using the following sample data (taken from [this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010659/select-top-3-unexpexted-result/22010812#22010812):

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Score float
)    

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1, 'Tom',8.9)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2, 'Jerry',8.9)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (3, 'Sharti',7)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (4, 'Mamuzi',9)
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (5, 'Kamala',9)
```

Traditional `OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Take(3)` will result with: <kbd>Mamuzi</kbd>, <kbd>Kamala</kbd> and *one of* <kbd>Tom</kbd> (*or* <kbd>Jerry</kbd>) where it should include ***BOTH***

I know there is no built-in equivalent of it and i've found a way to implement it. I don't know if it is the best way to do it and open for alternative solutions.

Comment: I think you're going to need a `Where()` method in there; the `Take()` method is non-deterministic.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I suppose no way to do it with `Take()` only, but how to make use of `Where()` ?

Comment: One of the links were incorrect, just corrected them.

Comment: Well I think you'd probably need to get a distinct list of the  top 3 scores, then get a list of `Person` objects whose scores are equal to or greater than the least of the top 3 scores.  It's a bit ugly, SQL-wise, but I have yet to see an ORM handle windowed functions with any degree of facility.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs i suppose Pumpkin's answer was inspired by your comment up there. Imo it didn't get that *ugly*, at least not as much as i expected (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var query = (from q in list.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score).Take(3).Select(s => s.Score).Distinct()
             from i in list
             where q == i.Score
             select i).ToList();
```

Edit:

@Zefnus

I wasn't sure in which order you wanted it but to change the order you can put a OrderBy(s => s.Score) between *select i* and *ToList()*

I don't have the possibility to check what sql statement my linq clause would produce. But your answer is much better i think. And your question was also really good. I never thought about top with ties in linq. ;)

Basically it only takes top 3 scores from the first list and compares them with the whole list and i takes only those scores which are equal to the scores of the first list.

Comment: Hey Pumpkin, welcome to SO. Nice answer, it worked well altho the result is in reverse order. Can you share some description as well ?

Comment: +1 for the additional. Thank you Pumpkin, your answer inspired my new idea (check my new solution - 2nd answer), and implementation of *extension method*

Answer (score 2):

### Do not use `IEnumerable<T>` with anything touching a database!

A solution aimed at [LinqToSql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and [LinqToEntities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should not be using [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your current self answer will result in every single person being selected from the database and then being queried in memory using [LinqToObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx).

To make a solution that is translated to SQL and executed by the database you have to use [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> TopWithTies<T, TComparand>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TComparand>> topBy, int topCount)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (topBy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("topBy");
        if (topCount < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("topCount", string.Format("topCount must be greater than 0, was {0}", topCount));

        var topValues = source.OrderBy(topBy)
                              .Select(topBy)
                              .Take(topCount);

        var queryableMaxMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                  .Single(mi => mi.Name == "Max" &&
                                                                mi.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                                                                mi.IsGenericMethod)
                                                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TComparand));

        var lessThanOrEqualToMaxTopValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
                topBy.Body,
                Expression.Call(
                    queryableMaxMethod,
                    topValues.Expression)),
            new[] { topBy.Parameters.Single() });

        var topNRowsWithTies = source.Where(lessThanOrEqualToMaxTopValue)
                                     .OrderBy(topBy);
        return topNRowsWithTies;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> TopWithTiesDescending<T, TComparand>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TComparand>> topBy, int topCount)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (topBy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("topBy");
        if (topCount < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("topCount", string.Format("topCount must be greater than 0, was {0}", topCount));

        var topValues = source.OrderByDescending(topBy)
                              .Select(topBy)
                              .Take(topCount);

        var queryableMinMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                  .Single(mi => mi.Name == "Min" &&
                                                                mi.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                                                                mi.IsGenericMethod)
                                                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TComparand));

        var greaterThanOrEqualToMinTopValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                topBy.Body,
                Expression.Call(queryableMinMethod,
                                topValues.Expression)),
            new[] { topBy.Parameters.Single() });

        var topNRowsWithTies = source.Where(greaterThanOrEqualToMinTopValue)
                                     .OrderByDescending(topBy);
        return topNRowsWithTies;
    }
}
```

This creates queries of the following form:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Score]
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Score] >= ((
    SELECT MIN([t2].[Score])
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (3) [t1].[Score]
        FROM [Person] AS [t1]
        ORDER BY [t1].[Score] DESC
        ) AS [t2]
    ))
ORDER BY [t0].[Score] DESC
```

[That query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ce4c/3) is only about 50% worse than the [baseline query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ce4c/2):

```sql
SELECT TOP (3) WITH TIES
    [t0].[Id], 
    [t0].[Name], 
    [t0].[Score]
FROM 
    [Person] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[Score] desc
```

With a data set consisting of your original 5 records and an additional 10000 records all with scores less than the original both of these are more or less instant (less than 20 milliseconds).

The `IEnumerable<T>` approach took a whole **2 minutes**!

---

If the expression building and reflection seems scary the same thing can be achieved with a join:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> TopWithTiesDescendingJoin<T, TComparand>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TComparand>> topBy, int topCount)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (topBy == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("topBy");
    if (topCount < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("topCount", string.Format("topCount must be greater than 0, was {0}", topCount));

    var orderedByValue = source.OrderByDescending(topBy);
    var topNValues = orderedByValue.Select(topBy).Take(topCount).Distinct();
    var topNRowsWithTies = topNValues.Join(source, value => value, topBy, (x, row) => row);
    return topNRowsWithTies.OrderByDescending(topBy);
}
```

With the following [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ce4c/4) as the result (with about the same performance):

```sql
SELECT [t3].[Id], [t3].[Name], [t3].[Score]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[Score]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (3) [t0].[Score]
        FROM [Person] AS [t0]
        ORDER BY [t0].[Score] DESC
        ) AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
INNER JOIN [Person] AS [t3] ON [t2].[Score] = [t3].[Score]
ORDER BY [t3].[Score] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, i already stated that it was _not efficient_ but i agree that avoiding `IEnumerable` and using `IQueryable` with `Expression` is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution - *which probably is not as efficient as the* [*other solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157211/linq-to-entities-equivalent-of-sql-topn-with-ties/22159080#22159080) - is to get `TOP(3)` *Scores* and get the rows with *Score* values contained in the `TOP(3)`.

We can use `Contains()` as follows;

```
orderedPerson = datamodel.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score);

topPeopleList =
(
    from p in orderedPerson 
    let topNPersonScores = orderedPerson.Take(n).Select(p => p.Score).Distinct()
    where topNPersonScores.Contains(p.Score)
    select p
).ToList();
```

What's good about this implementation is that it's ***extension method*** `TopWithTies()` can be implemented easly as;

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TopWithTies<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, TResult> selector, int n)
{
    IEnumerable<T> orderedEnumerable = enumerable.OrderByDescending(selector);

    return
    (
        from p in orderedEnumerable
        let topNValues = orderedEnumerable.Take(n).Select(selector).Distinct()
        where topNValues.Contains(selector(p))
        select p
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you can do something like:

```
OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Skip(2).Take(1)
```

Count the number of occurrences of this element, and then:

```
OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Take(2 + "The select with the number of occurrences for the third element")
```

I think that maybe this works ;)
It´s only an idea!

Comment: + 1 For the idea of `.Skip(n - 1).Take(1)` in order to get *last row* Oscar, but your answer is incomplete that might be the reason someone downvoted.

Comment: Yes.. Maybe! ;) But thanks for the +1! That´s why I put at the end that was only an idea! ;) Congrats Zefnus!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution taking the `Score` field value of the `N`th row (3rd row in this case) using `.Skip(n-1).Take(1)` and selecting all rows with score value greater or equal to that as follows:

```
qryPeopleOrderedByScore = datamodel.People.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score);

topPeopleList =
(
    from p in qryPeopleOrderedByScore
    let lastPersonInList = qryPeopleOrderedByScore.Skip(2).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
    where lastPersonInList == null || p.Score >= lastPersonInList.Score
    select p
).ToList();
```

Comment: More or less the same that I said ;) I am glad that you found the solution! Congrats!

Comment: @OscarBralo Thank you. The idea of taking last row using `Skip` and `Take` was nice but the rest was done with filtering for score value using where