# "LINQ to Entities" can't project field of single row since Expression<Function<>> has no Invoke() method

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

Building on to the question of *[LINQ to Entities equivalent of TOP(n) WITH TIES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157211/linq-to-entities-equivalent-of-sql-topn-with-ties)*, I'm trying to implement an *extension method* to provide `SQL` `WITH TIES` functionality in `LINQ`, and i could accomplish this for `IEnumerable<T>` as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157211/linq-to-entities-equivalent-of-sql-topn-with-ties/22191493#22191493) suggests;

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TopWithTies<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, TResult> selector, int n)
{
    IEnumerable<T> orderedEnumerable = enumerable.OrderByDescending(selector);

    return
    (
        from p in orderedEnumerable
        let topNValues = orderedEnumerable.Take(n).Select(selector).Distinct()
        where topNValues.Contains(selector(p)) // # selector.Invoke(p); could be used aswell
        select p
    );
}
```

Which runs returning expected results, but since with `IEnumerable<T>` (I believe) the execution takes places *immediately*, I decided to convert it to `IQueryable<T>` to ensure *deferred execution* as follows;

```
public static IQueryable<T> TopWithTies<T, TResult>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector, int n)
{
    IQueryable<T> orderedList = queryable.OrderByDescending(selector);

    return
    (
        from p in queryable.OrderByDescending(selector)
        let topNValues = queryable.OrderByDescending(selector).Take(n).Select(selector).Distinct()
        where topNValues.Contains(selector(p)) // # Doesn't compile, no .Invoke() method is defined
        select p
    );
}
```

Everthing is fine except `selector(p)`. `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` has no `Invoke()` method and can not be used as a `delegate`.

As parameter of `Contains()` method, how will i *select* the **field** that was used for **order by**?

I'm stuck at this point, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think missing link here is the fact that selector changed from a delegate to an expression.

If you change your

```
where topNValues.Contains(selector(p))
```

to

```
where topNValues.Contains(selector.Compile()(p))
```

at least it will compile. But in doing so, I'm not sure exactly what is being materialised, so it's important that you check the generated SQL to see if it is as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for answering an old question after a long time. For `Compile()`; I never gave it a change thinking that, in case it would behave like the `IEnumerable<T>` overload. My intention was to ensure *Deferred* execution. I'm afraid using `Compile()` will most likely cause *Immediate* execution. Anyway, in order to find out I'll need to give it a try.