# How to get top 1 record of each group order by desc in SQL Server using linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to get top 1 record order by `updatedtime` (latest) desc. I'm unable to filer top 1 record from my table

```
select watertowerid, DOValue, PHValue, WaterTemperature, CurrentTime 
from ParkingSlots 
group by watertowerid, PHValue, DOValue, WaterTemperature, CurrentTime
```

Sample data:

```
PHValue DOValue WaterTemperature   watertowerid   CurrentTime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3.00     4.00      22.00               1         2016-09-29 02:34:00
 6.00     4.00      33.00               2         2016-11-29 02:34:00
 8.22     6.55      28.22               1         2016-06-25 01:25:00
30.52     5.60      27.00               2         2016-08-29 02:34:00
```

Desired output:

```
PHValue  DOValue   WaterTemperature    watertowerid    CurrentTime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3.00     4.00         22.00               1          2016-09-29 02:34:00
  6.00     4.00         33.00               2          2016-11-29 02:34:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WITH TIES

```
select TOP(1) with ties *
from ParkingSlots 
order by row_number() over(partition by watertowerid order by CurrentTime DESC);
```

Comment: do u have any idea how to write this query in linq

Comment: Linq has no direct analog. See this topic for options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157211/linq-to-entities-equivalent-of-sql-topn-with-ties

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_number()` function and find latest rows based on currenttime column value.

```
SELECT [PHValue], [DOValue], [WaterTemperature], [watertowerid], [CurrentTime]
    FROM   (SELECT *,
                   Row_number()
                     OVER(
                       partition BY [watertowerid]
                       ORDER BY currenttime DESC) rno
            FROM   ParkingSlots)a
    WHERE  rno = 1
```

Comment: its correct.can u help me how to write in linq query

Comment: @Swapna Sorry i don't know about linq.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (PHValue int, DOValue int, WaterTemperature int, watertowerid int, CurrentTime datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table2

VALUES
    (3.00, 4.00, 22.00, 1, '2016-09-29 02:34:00'),
    (6.00, 4.00, 33.00, 2, '2016-11-29 02:34:00'),
    (8.22, 6.55, 28.22, 1, '2016-06-25 01:25:00'),
    (30.52, 5.60, 27.00, 2, '2016-08-29 02:34:00')
;


;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY watertowerid ORDER BY CurrentTime DESC) AS rn
   FROM Table2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1

SELECT *
FROM Table2 D
WHERE CurrentTime = (SELECT MAX(CurrentTime) FROM Table2 WHERE watertowerid = D.watertowerid)
```

Comment: what is table2 here?i have only one table

Comment: table name ..@Swapna

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ (this is assuming Entity Framework, other providers will be similar):

```
var res = from ps in context.ParkingSlots
          group new { ps.watertowerid, ps.PHValue, ps.DOValue, ps.WaterTemperature, ps.CurrentTime } into groups
          from grp in groups
          let top = (from ps in grp
                     orderby ps.updatedtime
                     select ps).FirstOrDefault()
          where top != null
          select top;
```

should do it. The second `from` iterates through the groups allowing ordering, and thus `FirstOrDefault` in each group. The null check shouldn't be needed (would need an empty group) but with EF to Entities you cannot use `First` on an inner query.

Comment: getting error.  invalid expression term "by" and the name "g" does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Swapna Typos: should now be fixed (but this is a sketch of an answer to get you in the right direction not a tested solution).